# 403 Forbidden Nginx

Tags: html, nginx

I am using nginx as web server for running html contents. When I copy my index.html into /usr/share/nginx destination it is working fine loading web page. But my project located in /var/www/example.com directory. When i give that path into nginx.conf it is getting error 403 Forbidden.

Below I attached nginx.conf.

[image: nginx]

i am new to this and any suggestions would be really helpful.

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;`enter code here`
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/example.com;
    index         index.html;



    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }
```

Comment: If you run `ls -ld /usr/share/nginx/html /var/www/example.com`, what’s the output? Also, please include the entire nginx.conf using code formatting (the `{}` button in the toolbar).

Comment: @Ry- `drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 94 Nov 13 12:07 /usr/share/nginx/html`
`drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 56 Nov 13 12:46 /var/www/example.com`

Comment: @Ry- I put my nginx.conf file.

Comment: `ls -ld /var/www` as well?

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x. 3 root root 22 Nov 13 12:29 /var/www`

Comment: Oh, I guess the relevant one: `ls -l /var/www/example.com/index.html`. Also try `sudo -u nginx cat /var/www/example.com/index.html`.

Comment: when I run it, getting `index.html` contents. `-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 1545 Nov 13 12:46 /var/www/example.com/index.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183605/discussion-between-janith-and-ry).

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect file permissions are another cause of the "403 Forbidden" error. The standard setting of 755 for directories and 644 for files is recommended for use with NGINX. The NGINX user also needs to be the owner of the files.

Identify the NGINX User
To begin, you will need to determine what user NGINX is running as. To do this, use the command:

ps -ef | grep nginx

Check the first column, for any of the NGINX worker processes:

In this example, the NGINX worker process is running as the user nginx.

Set File Ownership
Go to the directory above the website's document root. For example, if your website's document root is /usr/share/nginx/example.com go to /usr/share/nginx with the command:

cd /usr/share/nginx

Change the ownership of all the files from this point down to the nginx user with the command:

sudo chown -R nginx:nginx *

Set the permissions of each directory at this location to 755 with the command:

sudo chmod 755 [directory name]mixed
For example, to set the permissions of the example.com directory, the command is:

sudo chmod 755 example.commixed
Then go to the web document root directory:

cd example.commixed
Change the permissions of all the files in this directory with the command:

sudo chmod 644 *

Comment: did you restart nginx server?

Comment: Yes I did. When I put my project index.html into the /usr/share/nginx directory, working fine. But I want to run it from /lib/www/example.com directory

Comment: kindly check files in following location  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

Comment: I don't have `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` directories in `/etc/nginx`

Comment: If you installed from the official NGINX repository, this line will say include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; as it does in the http block above. Each website you host with NGINX should have its own configuration file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/, with the name formatted as example.com.conf. Sites which are disabled (not being served by NGINX) should be named example.com.conf.disabled.